# ng-click/onClick not working on <object>

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm not able to invoke functions when I click on an image that is present in the  tag. Particularly, I want to zoom and pan the image. These functions work well with image tag but not with object tag.

I've put debugger on the functions that are called 'on click' and also have put some alert pop ups on click but none of them seem to work. How can I get them working?

Below is my code.

```
<object ng-click="zoomService.activateZoomAndPan();"
        tb-refresh-graphic="tocService.acti‌​ve_node.activeGraphic">
</object>
```

Comment: Will you please share your code ?

Comment: the ng-click functions are not getting invoked on click of the object tag. if we put an image tag instead they work well.

Comment: Just a wild guess. Is zoomService a property on your scope?  In your directive/controller file, you should have something like: `$scope.zoomService = zoomService;`

Comment: yes, zoom service is a function in the service class

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a direct problem with `<object>` and `ng-click`. See http://plnkr.co/edit/jqQKkbLIxxepggRXoxht?p=preview. What does the other attribute do? Is it a directive?

Comment: Can you please share the controller code?

Comment: cant share the code...

Comment: on further analysis i realized that the object tag is clickable but the SVG image inside that is not getting clicked. what can be the cause?

Comment: Probably a click event listener on the SVG that stops event propagation. Without knowing how the contents of your `<object>` tag are created, it's impossible to answer.